# How can I create a combobox with saving value in javascript (similar to google CategoryFilter Control)

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, google-api, google-visualization

I want to have on my html-site an combobox like on the following img. I want to get the selected values and print in out. How can I create this comboBox?? I have tried the Google API Visualization CategoryFilter Control. But you can not customize the google control.

[image: ComboBox]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just mocked up a combo-box like you described: http://jsfiddle.net/twwGM/

Basically, you need to use JS to capture the `onchange` event of the select box, and then append its value to some target area with specific styling by generating an HTML string from your function. Keep styles out of the JS and instead style it through the use of a CSS class.

HTML Markup:

```
<form>
    <select id="selector">
        <option>Magic</option>
        <option>Canaries</option>
        <option>Unicorns</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="target-area"></div>
```

JS Code

```
(function () {

    document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("change", function () {
        var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        var genId = val + "-close";
        if (!document.getElementById(genId)) {
            var htmlstr = "<div class='pasted-option'>" + val + "<span id='" + genId + "'>x</span></div>";
            var targetArea = document.getElementById("target-area");
            targetArea.innerHTML += htmlstr;
            var closeButton = document.getElementById(genId);
            closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                var parent = this.parentNode;
                parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
            });
        }
    });

}(window));
```

As you can see within the code, we also generate an id for the span based on the item's name so that we can make a call to it later for removal from the list. It also gives us the ability to check and make certain the value doesn't already exist within the list.